# Why a constant integer pointer point to a non constant integer allowed?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I'm currently trying to learn some C++ and came across following unintuitive behavior. As `t` is a pointer to a `const int` I would expect `*t` to stay the same as long as we do not change `t`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int a = 3;
    const int* t = &a; //Why is this allowed? a is NOT const int
    a = 4;
    cout << *t << endl; //This does then print 4
    //*t = 4; //Throws error.

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone explain why this is does compile?

Comment: to clear the confusion i would suggest to start without pointers. `int a = 1; const int b = a;` is just fine, and now `b` is const while `a` is not, even if the hold the same value

Comment: @tobi303 Yes, but in your example `b` receives a *copy* of the value of `a`.

Comment: well, then what about `int a = 1; const int& b = a;` now `b` is a reference for `b`, but you cannot change the value through `b` even if `a` is not const

Comment: @tobi303 Ok, originally would not have expected this to work as well. But now I get the idea of the *responsibilty* as someone called it below, so that makes sense, thank you for your help!

Comment: pass by value is usually done via `void foo(const T&)` this just means, that inside the function, the value cannot change, but the parameter passed to the function is not necessarily `const`

Comment: ...one last comment: `const` is mainly to check that the programmer doesnt make mistakes. Afaik once the compiler checked the const correctness all `const` is removed from the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As t is a pointer to a `const int` I would expect `*t` to stay the same as long as we do not change `t`.

You cannot make that assumption in general, because `t` might point to a non-const object, such as in your example.

```
const int* t = &a; //Why is this allowed? a is NOT const int
```

> Can anyone explain why this is does compile?

The rules of c++ allow the implicit conversion of `T*` to `const T*`. It is allowed, because it's very useful to have a pointer-to-const (or reference) to an non-const object. Pointer to const simply means that the object cannot be modified "through" the pointer. The object itself could be const, or non-const.

As an example of why it is useful, you could have some modifiable state as a private member of an object, and return `const` view to it so that others can observe, but not modify. A practical example of such is `std::string::c_str()`. It returns a `const char*` even though the internal buffer of the `std::string` is non-const.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation !t makes sense now when thinking of the type as what you can do *through* that exacty variable.

Answer (score 4):

`const int* t` just means you can't change the value `t` pointing to by `t`, nothing more. The original value might be changed, but it has nothing to do with `t`'s responsibility.

If you want to ensure the value won't be changed, you should let `t` point to a const, such as

```
const int a = 3;
const int* t = &a;
```

And for this case, you can't make a `int*` pointer point to it.

```
int* t = &a; // error
```

Comment: That makes sense. I expected that `const int*` can only accept adresses to `const int`!

Comment: @flawr `int*` could be implicitly casted to `const int*`, it just means you won't change the value via it. For example you could pass a `int*` to function, if you won't change the value inside the function, you can make the function takes `const int*` as the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

> As `t` is a pointer to a `const int` I would expect `*t` to stay the same as long as we do not change `t`.

The answer is simple: the `const` keyword in a pointer type declaration does not mean 'it is constant' but rather 'you are not allowed to modify it'.

This is useful for example when you create a variable and then call another function to do something with it, but you want to forbid modification:

```
    extern int countZerosInArray( const int *array, int arrayLen);

    int myVariableArray[ 100 ];
    // ... fill the array - i.e. modify it!
    int noOfZeros = countZerosInArray(myVariableArray, 100);
```

The `countZerosInArray` function is told  it has read-only access to the array, although the array itself of course is not constant.

Answer (score -4):

`const int* t = &a; // int* or const int* can assgin to const int*`